# Mysql maximum rows in a variable timeframe

Tags: mysql, date, count, timestamp

I'm making a fitness logbook where indoor rowers can log there results.
To make it interesting and motivating I'm implementing an achievement system. 
I like to have an achievement that if someone rows more than 90 times within 24 weeks they get that achievement.

Does anybody have some hints in how i can implement this in MYSQL. 
The mysql-table for the logbook is pretty straightforward: id, userid, date (timestamp),etc (rest is omitted because it doesn't really matter)

The jist is that the first rowdate and the last one can't exceed the 24 weeks.

Comment: This question is very hard to implement in mysql. Am I correct to assume, the 24weeks is the duration given from the 1st time of row ... until the 90th time of row?

Comment: Yes i would like it to arbitrary but i agree with you that it would  be hard to implement. On the other hand the achievements are checked after submitting a new logentry. I could just calculate if in the preceding 90 logs are actually in those 24 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your application that you want the most recent 24 weeks.

In mysql, you do this as:

```
select lb.userid
from logbook lb
where datediff(now(), lb.date) >= 7*24
group by userid
having count(*) >= 90
```

If you need it for an arbitrary 24-week period, can you modify the question?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a sql query to count the number of rows a user has between now and 24 weeks ago.  This is a pretty straight forward query to run.

Look at using something with `datediff` in mysql to get the difference between now and 24 weeks ago.

After you have a script set up to do this, set up a cron job to run either every day or every week and do some automation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a table achievers which you populate with the achievers of each day.
You can set a recurrent(daily, right before midnight) event in which you run a query like this:

```
 delete from achievers;

 insert into achievers (
 select userid
 from logbook
 where  date < currenttimestamp and date > currenttimestamp - 24weeks
 group by userid 
 having count(*) >= 90
 )
```

For events in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the list of users total activity in 24 weeks

```
   select * from table groupby userid where  `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 168 DAY ) AND CURDATE( ) having count(id) >= 90
```